# Cassandra installation Failed 64-bit check. Re-running to get version from 32-bit on windows 10

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have installed datastax-ddc-64bit-3.8.0 in windows 10 and tried to start the service by running the cassandra.bat in the bin folder. The service not started and failed with below message.

```
Detected powershell execution permissions.  Running with enhanced startup scripts.
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*

    WARNING!  Automatic page file configuration detected.
    It is recommended that you disable swap when running Cassandra
    for performance and stability reasons.

*---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*
Failed 64-bit check. Re-running to get version from 32-bit
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*

    WARNING! Detected a power profile other than High Performance.
    Performance of this node will suffer.
    Modify conf\cassandra.env.ps1 to suppress this warning.

*---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*
Cassandra 3.0 and later require Java 8u40 or later.
```

How to fix it?

Comment: I solve this indicating the right JAVA_HOME path (i.e., the 64bit vesrion of JRE 8.x.x).

Answer (score 6):

I solved this issue by pointing `JAVA_HOME` to `jre1.8.0_212` instead of JDK.

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra did not work with the 64-bit version of the JDK, I had to point my `JAVA_HOME` to the 64-bit version of the JRE. `cqlsh` doesn't work with latest Python, try Python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the JAVA x64 directory as the value in the JAVA_HOME environment variable.

When changing the JAVA_HOME directory, restart your console (Terminal, CMD, PowerShell, etc.)